# Connect via angular 4 http post to b a java rest api not allowed on server side

Tags: java, json, angular, rest, http

I have a angular 4 cliente service that calls a rest method declared on a java server with a Postmapping annotation.

When I call it from angular it is not accepted by the server. But trying it on postman it works when I add only the header Content-Type application/json.

With the same header added or even some others it still doesn't work from the angular.

Here the code on angular service:

```
public login(username: string, password: string): Observable<{}> {

const requestParam = {
  username: username,
  password: password,
  email: 'email@at.pt'
};

const options = this.generateOptions();

const body = JSON.stringify(requestParam);
return this.http
    .post(AuthService.SIGNIN_URL, body, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The headers I have at the  moment:

```
const headers = new Headers({
 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, 
 DELETE, OPTIONS',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-
 Auth-Token',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 });
```

And the given error on the browser:

```
2zone.js:2744 OPTIONS 
http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login net::ERR_ABORTED 
invokeTask @ zone.js:1427 globalZoneAwareCallback @ 
zone.js:1445 login?returnUrl=%2F:1 Failed to load 
http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login: Response to 
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
 requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is 
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP 
status code 403. auth.service.ts:205 Server error
```

The server side is using spring-boot:

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

```
/**
 * Returns authentication token for given user
 * 
 * @param authenticationRequest
 *            with username and password
 * @return generated JWT
 * @throws AuthenticationException
 */
@PostMapping(LOGIN_URL)
public ResponseEntity getAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("on login server side");
   ...
}   

 public class  JwtAuthenticationRequest implements Serializable {

private String username;
private String email;
private String password;
...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does server side use spring? Could you share for us your server side?

Comment: added detail for the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create this on server side:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

And above your method you should also add `@CrossOrigin` like this:

```
@CrossOrigin 
@PostMapping(LOGIN_URL)
public ResponseEntity getAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("on login server side");
   ...
}
```

Comment: It worked with a slight modification since WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated on the spring 5.0.0 I did in the way as my answer.

Comment: @b.lopes, thank you for your addition. Actually I didn't know what version of spring is used in your project =)

Comment: I added both annotation and WebConfig class, but I still can't catch the POST requests from angular ... even if those sent with postman are catched :o 
Any clue please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
}
```

instead of  using WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but it should work too as Roman Danilov post